# jQuery - change dropdown selected color based on last character

Tags: jquery, css, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to color the selected option of a page that has many dropdowns, the color signifies who is preferred and who is available. My problem is the selected options are not colored, only the options.

```
$("#InterviewManagementFrm .ddlInterviewer option:selected").each(function (index, value) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var lastChar = text.substr(text.length - 1)

    if (lastChar === 'A') {
        console.log(value);
        $(value).css("background-color", "#FECB00");
    }
    else if (lastChar === 'P') {
        console.log(value);
        $(value).css("background-color", "#99FF66");
    }
});
```

**Log**

```
 main.js:95
<option value=​"31748236-d0eb-422d-9a0a-3e58da0cc3d2" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8264a677-bb6d-4b7e-b65a-a96b6806bc94" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"ffe25d81-9ca5-48dd-98a3-19af881ec1b7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"ffe25d81-9ca5-48dd-98a3-19af881ec1b7" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"ffe25d81-9ca5-48dd-98a3-19af881ec1b7" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"ffe25d81-9ca5-48dd-98a3-19af881ec1b7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"ffe25d81-9ca5-48dd-98a3-19af881ec1b7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8264a677-bb6d-4b7e-b65a-a96b6806bc94" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8264a677-bb6d-4b7e-b65a-a96b6806bc94" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d07b7e2d-330e-4806-838f-c20f5e3db98b" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"d07b7e2d-330e-4806-838f-c20f5e3db98b" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4de1036f-1f62-4f84-9f80-b7bc5d6a6fce" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"4de1036f-1f62-4f84-9f80-b7bc5d6a6fce" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"4de1036f-1f62-4f84-9f80-b7bc5d6a6fce" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"4fa9ee12-14ba-48a0-b6dc-90cae56179f7" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"0b77c04e-9aa5-4453-8ab1-105814008c71" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"PreferredPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:99
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"d6a8565f-67cb-4b8f-8f8a-7afad50bc9fa" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"8e4a82c7-fd91-4b6c-bd58-4d4703e7c811" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​ main.js:95
<option value=​"227a6abb-225c-4587-bc73-0f65baf74e2c" class=​"AcceptedPreference">​…​</option>​
```

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that the options are coloured but I want it all to be coloured.

Any jQuery guru want to help me out with this one?

Comment: your InterviewManagementForm has an ID, switch this to an class and change your jquery from "#Inter.." to ".Inter..". Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Olli1511 My selector definitely works, the problem is what I have shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
 $("#InterviewManagementFrm .ddlInterviewer option:selected").each(function (index, value) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var lastChar = text.substr(text.length - 1)

    if (lastChar === 'A') {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).parent().addClass("AcceptedPreference");
    }
    else if (lastChar === 'P') {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).parent().addClass("PreferredPreference");
    }
});
```

Because I have selected the option I need to travel up a bit to the parent and colour that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your HTML, but it looks like you are trying to add and remove the classes from the whole dropdown, not the selected option. You can add `option:selected` to only apply it to the selected element, so it might look something like this:

```
$("#myDropdown option:selected").addClass("MyClass");
```

Comment: I made changes to the function and I can see with the log that it's selecting the selected value of the dropdown. My problem now is that it doesn't add the class in the IF condition.

Comment: "In the screenshot you can see that the options are coloured but I want it all to be coloured." - Didn't you state that you want to color the selected option **only**, not the whole dropdown?

Comment: that is true but only because that part of the logic works already. I want everything to be coloured but it's where the select option is white is the problem.

Comment: I posted a solution, do you have code that does the same? Otherwise I'll mark my own as correct answer.

Comment: As I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve, I can't help any further. But apparently you found a solution yourself. Hope my answer helped anyway to get you to the right selector ;)

Comment: Ok, so in my page I have my dropdown boxes, each one has a selected option and then the other options. I wrote some jQuery where only the options were coloured and not the selected. Originally my if condition was wrong but yes your comments helped me in the right direction. I up voted your comment. Have a nice day.